# Problem with implementing a implied volaitility function in R

Tags: programming, implied-volatility

I am new to programming, and I have been exposed to the basic of R and Python. I have been trying to implement the volatility smile function using a unit root function(a traditional procedure) but I am running into problems. Here is the code I am writing:

```
BlackScholesFormulaBach  <- function (spot,timetomat,strike,r, q=0, sigma)
{ 
  
  d1<-(spot-strike)/(sigma*sqrt(timetomat))
  d2<-(spot-strike)/(sigma*sqrt(timetomat))
  
  
  result<-(spot-strike)*pnorm(d1)+sigma*sqrt(timetomat)*dnorm(d1)
  
  
  BlackScholesFormulaBach<-result
  
}

BlackScholesImpVol  <- function (obsprice,spot,timetomat,strike,r, q=0)
  
{ difference<- function(sigBS, obsprice,spot,timetomat,strike,r,q)
{BlackScholesFormulaBach(spot,timetomat,strike,r,q,sigBS)-obsprice
}

uniroot(difference, c(-1,1),obsprice=obsprice,spot=spot,timetomat=timetomat,strike=strike,r=r,q=q)$root

}

S_0<-100
cap_T<-1
sigma_1<-15
N<-1000

BlackScholesImpVol(S_0,cap_T,1,0,0,15)
```

Every time I run the code I get:

```
Error in c(-1, 1) : unused argument (1)
```

If I change the interval I get the same error. I have been checking the code but it seems right. I have consulted other people and none finds the problem. According to R the problem is on the unitroot function, but I fail to see where.

Question:

Can someone help me solve this implementation problem?

Thanks in Advnace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in the code you posted, but somewhere before: you have apparently defined a function called `c`, with only one argument.

Try to run the code in a new session.

Comment: Or try `rm(c)`.

Comment: You should be crystal clear removing any default function like `c`. Given the widespread usage of this function removing it with `rm` is really bad idea. Why not use some other name?

Comment: The function "c" is the list function, in order to build a vector. How should I have defined the function? Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: As pointed out by VDZ, you have `c` defined somewhere yourself, probably as a one argument function. It's not possible to delete the builtin `c`, in a fresh session `rm(c)` yields `Warning message: In rm("c") : object 'c' not found`. If you overwrite `c` it does work, for example: `c <- list; rm(c)` doesn't give a warning.

Comment: @BobJansen Thanks for your comment. That was indeed the problem. I have just used "rm" and it is working now.